# Bad seeking with JWPlayer + Nginx + ngx_http_mp4_module

Tags: nginx, streaming, video-streaming, mp4

We have a problem with seeking. Some of our videos works well, some freeze after seeking.

Nginx conf:

```
location ~ .mp4$ {
    mp4;
    mp4_buffer_size 1m;
    mp4_max_buffer_size 10m;

    limit_rate_after 5m;
    limit_rate 130k;
}
```

JWPlayer conf:

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
    wmode: "transparent",
    flashplayer: "/js/jwplayer/player.swf",
    file: "/files/videos/k7uvlzftdgsz.mp4",
    provider:'http',
    image: "/img/screenshots/k7uvlzftdgsz.jpg",
    autostart: true,
    height: 495,
    width: 880
});
```

The interesting is, that some videos freeze only sometimes, some freeze always and some freeze only in some part of timeline.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

add this:

`startparam: 'start',`

Comment: It's not clear which file you're suggesting the OP add this to. To `nginx.conf` or to `jwplayer.conf`? Also, it would be helpful to say why you think this will solve the problem.